# AWS API Gateway - change to 404 if query returns nothing

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have a Dynamodb table with a few fields - my_id is the PrimaryKey. In the API gateway I set up a response with a method that takes in a parameter `{my_id}`.

Then I have an Integration Request mapping template that takes the passed in parameter and queries the table to return all the fields that match.

Then I have an Integration response mapping template that cleans up the returned items the way I want.

This all works perfect.

The thing I can't figure out how to do is if the parameter that is passed in doesn't match anything in the table, how do I get it to change from a 200 status into a 404?

From what I can tell when the passed in parameter doesn't match anything it doesn't cause an error, it just doesn't return anything.

It seems like I need to change the mapping template on the Integration response to first check if the params are empty and then somehow tell it to change the response status.

I can find info about this type of thing with people using Lambda, but I am not using Lambda - just the Dynamodb table and the API Gateway.

Comment: Have you set up a Method Response of 404 for your API Gateway GET method? DynamoDB responses return an error code that you should be able to map to an API Gateway error code in the Integration Response. [Docs here] (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html)

Comment: The problem is that I am running a query and if the query returns no results there is no error. I would get an error if the table was wrong, but the table is never wrong as it is baked into the mapping template. I would like to have an error when the query returns no results.

Comment: The documentation here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) seems to indicate that you'll get a big JSON response that will include a  "Count": number pair -- it *looks* like you might be able to use the body mapping template of the Integration Response to parse the JSON and check if the Count element is 0 and map it to a 404 error -- more documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html

Comment: From that link you can get to this: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference.html which I think is what I need. Check count to see if zero is what I want to do, just wasn't clear what the syntax would be.

Comment: I made some progress - no problem to get the Count: 0 and control the content returned by the mapping template. But the problem is I am in the 200 response mapping template. All of the things I have read are based on Lambda, and having Lambda pass the error. I am not using Lambda, so the 200 integration response seems to be the first place to check for an error but it seems like I need to be one step before. Seems like I need to do something in the request response, but that is the request and I don't think it knows what it got yet.

Comment: Maybe this will help someone, though it doesn't do anything for the problem - here is how I checked the Count and returned a message in the body: `#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
#if($inputRoot.Count == '0' ) {"error":"no records"} #{else} /do your thing/ #end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Api gateway currently supports mapping the status code using the status code of the integration response (Here dynamodb response code). The only workaround is to use a lambda function which outputs different error messages that can be mapped using a error regex http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-execution-console.html.

Comment: Unfortunately this is true. Maybe they will change it one day.

Comment: I can confirm that API Gateway expects a response body along with status code 404, otherwise (empty body or a body that does not fit the message template) it will match the default response code, for me it was 200.

Answer (score 12):

You can use Mapping Template to convert the response that you get from DDB and overrride the response code. You can get more details in the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html

If you are using cloud formation, you can do this by using below snippet

```
IntegrationResponses:
  - StatusCode: "200"
    ResponseTemplates:
        application/json: |
          {
            "payload" : {
              }
            },
          }
IntegrationResponses:
  - StatusCode: "200"
    ResponseTemplates:
       application/json: |
                #set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
                #if($inputRoot.toString().contains("Item"))
                $input.json("$")
                #set($context.responseOverride.status = 200)
                #else
                #set($context.responseOverride.status = 404)
                #end
```